# Assuring $digest Is called Following non Angular Code Execution

Tags: angularjs

I have a UI component which has a `$watch` callback on its width (the reason is not relevant for this post).
The problem is that in some cases:

- The width is changed from a non angular context ->
- There is no `$digest` cycle ->
- **My `$watch` callback is not called**.

Eventhough my application is a full angular application there are still cases in which code is executed in non angular context. For example:
JQuery calles `window.setTimeout` - so even if my code called `JQuery` from within angular context the timeout callback is called in non angular context and my `$watch` callback will not be executed afterwards.

By the way, even angular themselves call `window.setTimeout` in their `AnimatorService`...

***So my question is***: 
How can I make sure a `$digest` cycle is always performed after any code is executed? (even when the code is a 3rd party code...)

I thought about overriding the original `window.setTimeout` method but:

- It feels a bit ugly and dangerous.
- I'm afraid it won't cover all use cases.

Adding a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2MMpqtIclepYw67MmtKD?p=preview).
The plunker sample contains:

- An element which can be hidden using JQuery `fadeOut` method.
- A button which executes the `fadeOut` call for hiding the element.
- A text showing the element display status (`Shown!!!` or `Hidden!!!`). This text is updated by `$watch`ing on the element `display` property.
- A button which does nothing but to initiate some angular code so that a `$digest` cycle is called.

**Flow:**

- Click the `Fade Out` button -> the element will be hidden but the status text will remain `Shown!!!`.
  You can wait forever now - or:
- Click the `Do Nothing` button -> suddenly the text will change.

**Why?**

When clicking the `Fade Out` button `JQuery.fadeOut` calls the `window.setTimeout` method. After that my `$watch` callback is called but the element is still not hidden.
The element is only hidden after the timeout callback is called - but then there is no `$digest` cycle (and i have no way that i know of to trigger one).
Only on the next time an angular code will run my `$watch` function will be called again and the status will be updated.

Comment: Why is [$scope.$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) not a solution?

Comment: Not exactly - the problem is that i cannot get any event when this code runs. As in the example, if some 3rd party (like JQuery or Angular) calls `window.setTimeout` my code will not be executed when the timeout callback is called so i cannot add a call to `$scope.apply` either.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to setup a plunker demo, because your case sounds quite unusual.

Comment: Added a plunker - hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS provides a special `$apply` method on the `scope` object to allow you to execute code from outside the AngularJS framework.

The `$apply` function will execute your code in the correct context and apply a `$digest` cycle afterwards so you don't have to deal with that yourself.

To implement it in your code, you can:

```
// Get element
var $element = $('#yourElement');

// Get scope
var scope = angular.element($element).scope();

// Execute your code
scope.$apply(function(scope){
    // Your logic here
    // All watchers in the scope will be triggered
});
```

(The scenario above can change depending on your actual application).

You can read more about the `$apply` method of the scope object right here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the detailed response. However, i'm afraid it doesn't help. I have no way of adding $apply call since the function making the change is not mine (it's a 3rd party -> JQuery). Please see the plunker I added.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your plunker, you could add a callback on the call to animate to manually trigger an update to the Angular scope once the animation is complete:

Before:

```
$scope.fadeOut = function() {
    animatedElement.fadeOut('slow');
};

var getDisplay = function() {
    return animatedElement.css('display');
};

$scope.$watch(getDisplay, function(display) {
    console.log('$watch called with display = `' + display + '`');
    $scope.display = display === 'none' ? 'Hidden!!!' : 'Shown!!!';
});
```

After:

```
$scope.fadeOut = function() {
    animatedElement.fadeOut('slow', function() { $scope.$digest(); });
};
```

This would cause your watch on getDisplay to be called when the animation is complete, by which time it will return the correct value.